# How do you test if two hashes (passwords) are similar?

Tags: php, hash, levenshtein-distance

When a user creates a password I hash it (including a salt) and save it in the DB.

Now when the user wants to change his or her password I want to test if the new one is too similar to the old one (I have seen this done on different services, especially online banking).

So, I thought I will use the `similar_text` or `levenshtein` function. And this works if the user has to type in his or her old password.

But when the user has forgotten their password, and they need to reset it, the obviously don't have to type in their old password. So I would need to compare the new password with the old password (saved in the DB), which I don't have in plain text but a hash.

Now, when I hash the new password using the same salt, and compare it with the old password (hashed), I obviously cannot test whether or not the new and old password are similar.

I am just curious to find out how companies do that, when they don't save the password as a plain text in the DB?

I couldn't really find anything helpful on Google. If anyone has any suggestions, or links to articles that discuss this in more detail, I'd appreciate it if they could share them.

Comment: You can't test for similarity with hashed values, only for equality

Comment: if it where possible then the hashing would be useless

Comment: This is not possible. Although only one character may differ, the hashes will be completely different.

Comment: Never seen any site check if the password is 'like', only if its equal. If they do check if its 'like', they probably store the password in clear text (which is less unusual than anyone would want to beleve..)

Comment: That's why I find it so confusing that they can say that the two passwords are too similar. Because "test" and "testt" might be considered completely different when hashed, whereas "test" and "$7of2ljf" might be similar when hashed.

Comment: @Jite - not necessarily stored in cleartext, but possibly encrypted rather than hashed (at least in the banking industry)

Comment: @MarkBaker Aye thats a posability too.

Comment: Rather than test similarity, you may find some companies testing if the same password has already been used within a period of time (eg over the last year) by storing a history of the hashes and comparing the new hash with those values in the history

Comment: @Mark, that's also a good point.

Comment: See also http://security.stackexchange.com/q/71756/971 for further solutions and some tricky issues that arise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach to test for similarity if the stored password is hashed (rather than encrypted) is to generate a number of likely permutations of the new password, hash the permutations, and see if any of those hashes correspond to the stored hash.

The rules for generating permutations would be the same as the rules for disallowed similarities.

**OLD**

```
password1
```

**NEW**

```
password2
```

**PERMUTATIONS**

```
password
password1   // This permutation's hash matches the stored hash.
password3
1password
etc...
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. As someone pointed out above even with a 1 character difference, the hashes will be completely different, even with something as outdated as MD5. If you're using a more updated method like PHPs password_hash, you won't even get the same hash if you run the same input more than once.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would make sense.

Comment: @AndrewBrown: You generate all permutations of the new password that would cause it to be invalid as being too similar to the old password, and then hash those permutations to see if any of them match the old hash.  Essentially it is trial-and-error based on rules to see if you can generate the old password from the new one.  For any hash function (assuming the same salt and number of hash iterations), you will always get the same output hash.  Otherwise, you could not use hashing for authentication.

Comment: @AndrewBrown you won't get the same input? How are you going to compare it afterwards?

Comment: i see what you're saying now, and it would work with MD5. but since we  shouldn't use that anymore, this method would fail with something like  password_hash, since hashes of the same input will be different everytime you run it. correct?

Comment: @eis did you mean the same output?

Comment: yes, output :) If for same input the hash would be different, how would it be used for comparing the passwords?

Comment: new php method to hash passwords: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php  It uses a variable salt (i believe), and the salt itself is stored in the resulting hash. the problem with simple hashes like MD5 (as you probably know) are rainbow tables, and this new method aims to help solve that

Comment: @AndrewBrown: You *must* use the same salt for a given user, otherwise the system could never know if the password entered by the user is the right one.  If the user entered a password and it always hashed to something *different* than what is stored in the database, the user would never be allowed in to the system.

Comment: @AndrewBrown, please consider removing all of your above comments. Not one of them is accurate and confuses future readers into thinking this method is wrong. This is the right answer.

Comment: I concede, after thinking about it, the above method would work

Comment: @AndrewBrown - Additionally, the new password_verify() also has a deliberate speed limiter to prevent brute-force attacks using the power of fast processors and GPUs to run millions of attempts per second

Answer (score 1):

In generating new password people usually create a random string for password and send it to user (by email or sms or anything else), and hash that string and save the hashed password in database.

you don't need to restore OLD password.hashing methods like `md5()` cannot be decrypted or restored, that is why we use them , for avoiding decryption by a hacker.

Comment: Maybe I should change my bank then. They require me to change my password every half a year or so, but they can tell if my new password is too similar to the old one.

Comment: It is a very *bad* idea to store the encrypted password in the base.  Just ask any number of high-profile websites that have had the encrypted passwords and the encryption key stolen.

Comment: *"hashing methods like md5() cannot be decrypted or restored"* --- and you stand by using `md5` (something that dates back to 1996) or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Comment: what's the problem? we dont need to decrypt them, am I wrong?

Comment: *md5* can absolutely be broken.  In fact, my nVidia graphic card is a 128-core processor md5 breaking machine http://3.14.by/en/md5 (note that **2009** hardware was brute forcing 350 million potential passwords / second on a single graphic card.  Serious hackers control botnets with thousands of computers that can all be cracking md5 via brute force.)

Comment: You would be surprised. If you only knew what's out there. @AlirezaFallah it would literally scare you.

Comment: Not that I do it for a living or anything :-)  But a few years ago my company asked me to figure out the password they had lost on a PDF (back when PDF's used md5).  It took 7 minutes on a conventional CPU.

Comment: are you saying brute force is decryption ?

Comment: 7 minutes in computer speed/age, that's like, well... 15 billion human years! @EricJ. that's a lot of computation.

Comment: its brute force, so its not decryption ;)

Answer (score 1):

After hashing two almost identical string (let's say one bit different) will have totally different hash... And it is possible that two totally different strings will have similar hash.

You cannot check password similarity when you are using password hashing or encryption. You can check only if the password is equal.

Plus you shouldn't restore old password. The policy is that user should always create a new password when he doesn't remember the old one.. If you allow them to restore/guess their password you are helping also attackers with cracking users passwords.